# AKTabBarController does not work when building for archiving

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, linker, uitabbarcontroller

I am using this in my project: https://github.com/alikaragoz/AKTabBarController

It works fine in the simulator but once I want to build in on my phone or make a ad-hoc built it fails. I don't really know how to understand the error messages. [image: The xCode error log when making a ad-hoc built]

Do I have to change something in the build settings? Traget is iOS 5 or higher.

Thanks for any help! Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look like you have multiples files on your project with the same name (maybe you added the AKTabBarController library twice)?

Try to clean up the project, see if you have duplicates and remove them. 
Then CMD+Shift+K and CMD+Shift+Alt+K

Possibly the same problem as stated here: [106 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727167/106-duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-armv7)

Comment: Thank you very much! I had the source files and the compiled framework both in my project. I simply deleted the framework. Thanks you saved my day. :D Thanks for the MD+Shift+K and CMD+Shift+Alt+K shortcut!